# Want to concatenate column of the second query to the first query but getting errors such as "query block has incorrect number of result columns"

Tags: sql, database, oracle, join, subquery

```
SELECT
    ID, PRIM_EMAIL, SEC_EMAIL, PHONE 
FROM
    STUDENTS.RECORDS
WHERE 
    ID IN (SELECT ID FROM STUDENTS.INFO WHERE ROLL_NO = '554')

UNION

SELECT NAME 
FROM STUDENTS.INFO 
WHERE ROLL_NO = '554';
```

Here `Roll_No` is a user inserted data so for now I have hard coded it. Basically with the help of `ROLL_NO` I sort the `STUDENTS_INFO` table from where I get the `ID` and based on that I try to get `PRIM_EMAIL`, `SEC_EMAIL`, `PHONE` from the `STUDENTS.RECORDS` table while matching the foreign keys of both the tables. In addition to the current result set I also want to have the prov_name column.

Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: A `UNION`'s both `SELECT`s must return the same number of columns.

Comment: You can do `UNION
select NAME, NULL, NULL, ... FROM ...` to get the same number.

Comment: Union takes two result sets and plops them together as one result. It's like copying and pasting rows in Excel. If you wanted a new column in your results, you would join or use a sub select.

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you want to put all this information on the same row, which suggests a `join` rather than `union all`:

```
select 
    r.ID,
    r.PRIM_EMAIL, 
    r.SEC_EMAIL,
    r.PHONE,
    r.NAME
from STUDENTS.RECORDS r
inner join STUDENTS.INFO i ON i.ID = r.ID
where I.ROLL_NO = '554';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the source of your error `query block has incorrect number of result columns` is coming from trying to union together a table with 4 columns (`id, prim_email, sec_email, phone`) with 1 column (`name`).

From your question, I am gathering that you want a single table of `id, prim_email, sec_email, phone` from `students.records` and `name` from `students.info`.

I think the following query using CTE's might get you (partially) to your final result.  You may want to refactor for optimizing performance.

```
with s_records as ( select * from students.records ),

s_info as ( select * from students.info ),

joined as ( 

  select
    s_records.id,
    s_records.prim_email,
    s_records.sec_email,
    s_records.phone,
    s_info.name

  from s_records

  left join s_info 
       on s_records.roll_no = s_info.roll_no

  where roll_np = '554' )

select * from joined
```

Overall, I think that a `join` will be part of your solution rather than a `union` :-)

Comment: GMB does this in a much more straight forward way without CTEs